# Netty - Framing

Tags: tcp, netty

I created [this small example](https://github.com/boldt/netty-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/de/dennisboldt/examples/TcpFraming). I have an `EchoServer` on Port 8080 and a `LogServer` on Port 9090 (exemplary in this example). Both are started on the same machine (with `Server`, which contains the main).

```
Server started on port 8080
Server started on port 9090
```

As soon a client -- via `telnet` -- connects, the `EchoServer` establishes a connection to the `LogServer`. Now I am entering a long text, let's say 5000 character (see the long_text in the example), even if bash cannot handle it:

```
EchoServer Received: 1024
LogServer Received: 1024
EchoServer Received: 2048
LogServer Received: 2048
EchoServer Received: 1025
LogServer Received: 1025
```

If I enter the text again, I am getting:

```
EchoServer Received: 2048
LogServer Received: 2048
EchoServer Received: 2049
LogServer Received: 2049
```

Let's do it again:

```
EchoServer Received: 3072
EchoServer Received: 1025
LogServer Received: 3072
LogServer Received: 1025
```

And again:

```
EchoServer Received: 4096
EchoServer Received: 1
LogServer Received: 4096
LogServer Received: 1
```

The last time:

```
EchoServer Received: 4097
LogServer Received: 4097
```

My observation:

First of all, the data is fragmented. Additionally, each time the fragmends are extended by 1024 bytes (1024,2048,3072,4096,...). <strike>I guess the last behavious is because of the TCP slow start</strike>.

<strike>How can I achive the forwarding to the `LogServer` without fragmentation, such my text will arrive as one single message? I guess the problem is, [how I connect to the `LogServer`](https://github.com/boldt/netty-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/de/dennisboldt/examples/TcpFraming/EchoServerHandler.java#L26)</strike>.

[**EDIT1**]

I changed the logs. It seems, that it's already happening between `telnet` and the `EchoSever`. <strike>Anyway, I still have the problem in the real environment. The whole message (some Kilobyte) is arriving via WebSockets and the Forwarding to another Connection is fragmented.</strike>

[**EDIT2**]

I did some more research (with wireshark -- [the log](http://paste.dennis-boldt.de/stackoverflow/9506146/wireshark.log)). I guess it has noting to do with TCP Slow Start. The data (I was sending 4095 times the letter `A`) arriving on the machine as three correct TCP packets:

1. Frame 1 (1506 bytes) with 1440 bytes TCP data (`41 41 41 ... 41 41 41`/HEX)
2. Frame 2 (1506 bytes) with 1440 bytes TCP data (`41 41 41 ... 41 41 41`/HEX)
3. Frame 3 (1283 bytes) with 1217 bytes TCP data (`41 41 41 ... 41 0d 0a`/HEX)

All 4095 `A` characters + CRLF arrived as expected.

The `EchoServer` said:

```
EchoServer Received: 1024
EchoServer Received: 2048
EchoServer Received: 1025
```

It also received the 4095 characters + CRLF, but it is different fragmented than the TCP segments (exactly same as the first log above). How can I avoid this Netty behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In non-blocking I/O, there's no practical way to get the number of available bytes in socket receive buffer.  Because of that problem, Netty *predicts* the number of available bytes.  It starts from 1024 and then increases the prediction depending the number of read bytes.  You can shcnage this behavior by employing a different prediction algorithm.

The default implementation is `AdaptiveReceiveBufferSizePredictor` and you might want to take a look into its source code to write your own one.

However, no matter what prediction algorithm you choose, you have to keep in mind that TCP/IP is a streaming protocol, which means you can always get messages in a split or merged form.  Please refer to the user guide: http://netty.io/docs/stable/guide/html/ (See the 'Dealing with a Stream-based Transport' section.)

Comment: Thanks for giving me some details. Finally I implemented something like the `LengthFieldPrepender` on application side. Thus, I leave the TCP behavior like it is and handle it in the application,

Comment: Doesn't it make sense to set the value to the standard Ethernet frame size -- 1500 Byte? In my opinion it should improve Netty not to extend the `ChannelBuffer` -- save some instructions -- for a single full frame.

Comment: Btw: am I right, that a `FIN` of a TCP-Paket always sends a Message to the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

You require a FrameDecoder in your pipeline can which assemble bytes from the network into complete frames. In your case I think you need to combine the StringDecoder and DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder. Take a look at the [Telnet example](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/telnet/package-summary.html) and specifically the [TelnetServerPipelineFactory](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/telnet/TelnetServerPipelineFactory.html)